# Css div with header and footer and dynamic content height

Tags: jquery, css, html

I want to construct a div that has a header with background like that
[image: header_bg]

some content with a background of one pixel repeated at y(or not?)

and a footer with background like that
[image: footer_bg]

resulting in something like that with some text in the div content(**Correct result**)
[image: Correct result]

I want to have the same result with 5 lines or 50 lines of text.

Right now i have this **HTML**

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="header"></div>
<div id="content">Text goes here
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this **CSS**

```
#header {
    width: 959px;
    height: 169px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    background: url(header.jpg);
}
#content {
    width: 959px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background: url(content.jpg);
    color: white;
}
#footer {
    width: 959px;
    height: 158px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    background: url(footer.jpg);
}
```

resulting in this(**Wrong result**)
[image: Wrong result]

I hope i demonstrated the problem clearly
Cheers

Comment: Do you have a link so I can check it out?

Comment: @J.T.S. http://infodim.eu/test2/test.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try that ?

HTML:

```
<div id="container_outer">
    <div id="container_inner">
        <div id="content">
             Your text goes here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#container_outer {
    background:url(images/body.png) repeat-y center center;
}
#container_inner {
    background:url(images/footer.png) no-repeat center bottom;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
#content {
    background:url(images/header.png) no-repeat center top;
    padding-top:10px;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't have done it your way (with big images) but with smaller footer + header images and a repeating body (placing the header / footer images on 2 divs in your content)

Answer (score 1):

you could add a negative margin to the #header and #content to pull the #content up over the header and the #footer up under the #content

```
#header{
    margin-bottom:-169px;
}

#content{
    margin-bottom:-158px;
}
```

the only problem is what happens with not much content the footer will be pulled up into the header but you can use the min-height on the #content to stop this
here is a jsfiddle of it http://jsfiddle.net/s295h/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
#header {
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
background: url(images/header.png);
}


#content {
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
background: url(images/body.png);
}



#footer {
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
background: url(images/footer.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give the #content element also a background-image with repeat-y which contains just the middle part of the image.

```
#content {
    background: url(images/body.png) repeat-y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#content p{
padding:10px;
width:939px;
}
```

add this to the css and write the text inside the content div within the

tags.

eg:

```
<div id="content"><p>content here</p></div>
```

Comment: @Coding-Freak.The problem i have is not in the padding.I know how to do that.The problem is that i want the text to be positioned on the top of the header and the footer.I think the images demonstrate the problem exactly.Please don't repost answers.Just edit the already given answer